# How to Calculate Number of Repeated Tests to Achieve a Target ICC?

Tags: simulation, intraclass-correlation

I am designing a case study and will be measuring something at baseline, periodically over time, and at post-testing. I will use the baseline measures to be able to calculate the 'minimum detectable change,' which I understand is heavily based on the ICC of the baseline measurement. How do I decide how many baseline tests are required to achieve a target ICC?

I've been attempting to simulate datasets and calculate their ICC's based on means and standard deviations reported in previous studies on that same measurement that I plan to take, however I'm not really sure how to do that in the first place, and what I'm getting is not working (for example, comparing 3 tests vs 6 tests vs 12 tests is still giving me all similar ICC values around 0.7, however, the prior research tends to find ICC values around 0.98).

If someone could please help me that would be amazing, I've been struggling with this for a very long time and can't find anything online that walks me through how to do this.